# NSURL and NSURLResponse syntax

Tags: swift2, nsurl, nsurlsession

`do catch` isn't working, this is the error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(NSURL?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSURL?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'

This is the code:

```
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

This is all The Code if it Helps:

```
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in       
  if (error == nil){
    let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)
    let weatherDictionary : NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: nil, error: NSError?) as! NSDictionary
    let currentWeather = Weather(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
      self.currentTemperature.text = "\(currentWeather.temperature)"
      self.iconView.image = currentWeather.icon!

      let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
      formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
      self.currentTime.text = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
      self.humidity.text = "\(Int(currentWeather.humidity * 100))%"
      self.rain.text = "\(Int(currentWeather.precipProbability))%"
      self.summary.text = "\(currentWeather.summary)"

      self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
      self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
      self.refreshButton.hidden = false
        })
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated as I am experiencing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second last error parameter from the call. And then use do catch blocks to handle the error.

```
sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL?, response: NSURLResponse?) -> Void in
```

Comment: That didnt work it asked me to put an exlamation mark so i did and then it just went back to the old error